# How to change the value of Auth::user() in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

Any way to change the user instance returned by `Auth::user()`, what I want is to eager load some relations with it, so i don't have to keep typing it every time:

from
`Auth::user();`
to 
`Auth::user()->with('company')->first();`

and every time I request the `Auth::user()` I get the `Auth::user()->with('company')->first()` returned.

Comment: What's wrong with `Auth::user()->company->whatever` ? Eager loaded data won't last past current request is over, so why do you need that?

Comment: I use `Auth::user()->company()` a lot, so I am trying this method hoping to cache it so I don't hit the database every time I request it.

Comment: You can use `->company` as dynamic property, so it's executed only once (per login / request), and of course you can cache the query in the relation definition on you `User` model. Pick whatever suits you.

Comment: Interesting, I will try it this way, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is to edit your `before` filter (`app/filters.php`).

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        Auth::setUser(Auth::user()->with('company')->first());
    }
});
```

That way you can still use `Auth::user()` wherever you need.

Answer (score 0):

One method which I follow is to set the Auth::user() in the BaseController and it will beaccessible in all the controllers. If you are using in Views you can View::share() to make it available in all views. Here you can eager load your relationships.

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

    protected $currentUser;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->currentUser = Auth::user(); // You can eager load here. This is will null if not logged in
    }

   protected function setupLayout()
   {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
             $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        } 

        View::share('currentUser', $this->currentUser);
  }
```

Comment: Sometimes I use `Auth::user()` outside of any `controller`, maybe this is helpful when working with the `view`.