# How to change only some value of Auth::user() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to change usertype of Auth::user()  value in laravel.

I went through this 
[How to change the value of Auth::user() in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040787/how-to-change-the-value-of-authuser-in-laravel-4)
but it seems not my problem.

I have a value `Auth::User()->usertype`

I want to change this value for specific users after login.

I try to assign the value like `Auth::User()->usertype = 1` But it is changed when redirect.

What is the correct way to change the value of Auth::user() object?

Comment: That it change back is because it takes the data out of the database. You must change it in the database.

Comment: I want to do it without changing the database.there is not the way to do it ?

Comment: Maybe you can store the data in a session?

Comment: you can assign it to session

Comment: Session::put('usertype',   1); you can put this after attempt call

Comment: @Szenis actually all the time those values get from database ? It may be keep the values as session or global variable like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use session after attempt call

```
   if (Auth::user()->attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'), 'password'=>Input::get('password') ), $rememberMe)) {
     //other stuff
     Session::put('usertype', 1);
     //other stuff
    }
```

And access like this anywhere

```
 Session::get('usertype')
```

Comment: The thing is Auth::user()->usertype is already lot of places in the code.I can't change those values.What I want is when super user login to the system change the privileges to normal users by changing the usertype value for specific tasks.

Comment: I want to access the values like Auth::user()->usertype

Comment: Auth::user()->usertype always fetches data from DB although what you want is correct but difficult to achieve without Session or may be by constant but again constant is somewhat difficult to achieve

Comment: Thanks @kamlesh.bar If it is get from database it is difficult for me to change those values.

Comment: One thing you can do is have OR condition and allow superadmin (sadmin usertype or normal user) to do task.

Comment: For do that I want to change all the places.I try to change it from one place.

Comment: ok. I don't think there is other better way other than or condition because that will not effect other working code and run smoothly

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eloquent $fillable vars, you can update the Model with

`\Auth::user()->update(['email' => 'youremail@email.com']);`